# Can not access ajax when I send data

Tags: jquery

That's how I use the strip as payment solution. I use my `console.log` to find out I get the right database with.

As soon as I need my `$.ajax` it will make 500 errors.

It can be seen here in the picture how my mistake looks.

[image]

on my line 33 are:

```
$.ajax({
```

My code:

```
function PayStripe() {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
    name: 'Test',
    description: 'Test abonnement',
    currency: "dkk",
    amount: $('#HiddenPrice').val() * 100,
    email: $('#Email').val()
    });
};

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_d4xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function (token) {
        token.subscriptionId = $('#SubscriptionId').val();
        token.City = $('#City').val();
        token.Postnr = $('#Postnr').val();
        token.Mobil = $('#Mobil').val();
        token.Adresse = $('#Adresse').val();
        token.CVRVirksomhed = $('#CVRVirksomhed').val();
        console.log(token.subscriptionId);
        console.log(token.City);
        console.log(token.Postnr);
        console.log(token.Mobil);
        console.log(token.Adresse);
        console.log(token.CVRVirksomhed);
        $.ajax({//error here
            data: JSON.stringify(token),
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/Stripe",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/Subscriptions/Succes';
            },
            error: function (errMsg) {
                //window.location.href = '/Subscriptions';
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        }); 
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
});
```

My Jquery is in my head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And my `StripeJsTest2.js` it is located at the bottom of the page.

That's how I work in .net core 2.0

Comment: It's not '500 errors', it's Error 500, witch means 'Server Internal Error'. Which indicates that the server had an internal problem, and possibly couldn't retrieve request.

Comment: this is server error

Comment: What can I do to get it fixe? @KlevinDelimeta

Comment: Well first you need to check the url and parameter request. You can use an app(extension for chrome) [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) to verify the validity of the request and it's parameters. 
Next i would check my code. But that's not related to your problem :)

Comment: the same error @KlevinDelimeta

Comment: Then your url is wrong. Try opening on browser. If it's still the same, url is not valid.

Comment: the top of my api/stripe have im `[Route("api/Stripe")]` so I do not think it's url wrong. i will try in firefox.